# Smack XMPP: Can't login to openfire server: "SASLErrorException: SASLError using DIGEST-MD5: not-authorized"

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I am trying to create a basic connection and login to an Openfire server that I have installed. I have the following user in my users database which I created through the Openfire web admin interface:

```
User: user
Password: 12345678
```

I can connect fine to the server as the connection returns true in my sout. The problem is when it tries to log in I get the following error:

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLErrorException: SASLError using DIGEST-MD5: not-authorized
```

I have the following code:

```
private XMPPConnection connection;

public void connect(String serverIP) {
    try {

        System.setProperty("smack.debugEnabled", "true");
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(serverIP, 5223);
        config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
        config.setSocketFactory(new DummySSLSocketFactory());    
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
        config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
        connection.connect();

        System.out.println("Connected: " + connection.isConnected());
        connection.login("user", "12345678");
        System.out.println("Logged in: " + connection.isAuthenticated());

    } catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    connectionHandler test = new connectionHandler();
    test.connect("localhost");
}
```

If anyone can correct what I am doing wrong I would be really grateful.

I have also tried the username as the email would be for example

```
user@localhost.com
or
user@localhost
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally managed to find the answer to this. The problem (possibly not even a problem) was that the authentication methods weren't set in the server config and as default allowed all methods. The first one chosen in java seems to be DIGEST-MD5 which was what was causing the errors. To fix this I added:

```
<sasl>
    <mechs> PLAIN </mechs>
</sasl>
```

before the last closing tag of the openfire.xml found in the config folder of the server. This can also be changed in the `ofproperty`  database table for the column called `sasl.mechs`.

Hopefully this helps someone (possibly me) in the future.

P.S. this is unsecure if not using SSL (port 5223 by default)

Comment: this was the right implementation. I'm using smack 4.1 and open fire 3.10.1 .Had been stuck for a few hours. Lets vote it up to save someone!

Comment: You should only use SASL PLAIN if you aware about its security implications.

Comment: @Flow agreed. In real world examples you should most definitely use a more encrypted method. The reason I opted for SASL PLAIN was because this was an in house application that had no external network access.

Answer (score 0):

> SASLError using DIGEST-MD5: not-authorized

This is most likely caused because you did not configure the correct XMPP domain (/service name) in your `ConnectionConfiguration`. DIGEST-MD5 would not only fail if the username or password is wrong, but also if the wrong XMPP domain is used.